# Why does insert change my list to None type?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, insert

```
animals = ["aardvark", "badger", "duck", "emu", "fennec fox"]
print(animals)

animals = animals.insert(2,"cobra")
print(animals)
```

Insert function turns list into None type:

[image]

I dont understand why this happens.

From python doc's:

> Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of
>   the element before which to insert, so a.insert(0, x) inserts at the
>   front of the list

Comment: `insert` is a method that modifies the list instance in-place.  It returns `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an in-place insertion with no return value.  Use this, instead.

```
animals.insert(2, "cobra")
print(animals)
```

Comment: Very interesting - how many in-place insertions exist in python?

Comment: Quite a few.  You have to read the description carefully to note whether the method works by return value, alteration of the object, or a combination of the two.

Comment: @RubenKAI Before using anything, you should read the documentation.

Comment: In general methods on mutable built-in objects like lists that are named after a verb and sound like they could modify (`insert`, `push`, `pop`, `sort`, `add`, `update`, etc.) modify in-place.  Operators (`+`, `-`, ...) and methods named after nouns (`set.difference()`, ...) return new objects. But as Prune said, to be sure read the documentation. There may be exceptions from the rule.

Answer (score 2):

The insert function does not return anything (or returns None, as Cong Ma noticed): it modifies the input list!

So just use the funtion without re-assigning the result (None!) to the variable:

```
animals = ["aardvark", "badger", "duck", "emu", "fennec fox"]
animals.insert(2,"cobra")
print(animals)
['aardvark', 'badger', 'cobra', 'duck', 'emu', 'fennec fox']
```

Comment: Technically, all Python functions return something.  Without the `return` statement, it returns `None`.